# Editing a manifest With java

Tags: java, command-line, manifest

I have just started my first Java program. I have created a batch file to run my command line arguments. In this program I am writing a "HelloWorld" string with HelloWorld.java

```
class HelloWorld
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    System.out.println("HelloWorld!!");
}
}
```

Now after I added java to my path I use the following in the .bat file.

```
 javac HelloWorld.java  //to complie
 java HelloWorld    //toRun
 jar -cvf HelloWorld.jar HelloWorld.class  //creating a archive
 jar -xf HelloWorld.jar  //Extracting and finding the manefest
```

From my jar file I now have to edit the manifest file and set the class I have just written as my main class for the jar file and I have done it as follow:

```
jar -cmf HelloWorld.jar Manifest.txt HelloWorld.class  //Here is the problem
java -jar HelloWorld.jar //here I am trying to run it
pause
```

I cant seem to edit the manifest. Do I have a Command prompt error or did I mistype something?

Comment: Does Manifest.txt exist on disk?  If yes.  Does it contain at least the following entry:  
Main-Class: HelloWorld

Comment: have you tried the verbose ouput option `-v` for the jar command?

Also, I believe you don't need to extract the jar before modifying the manifest.

Last but not least, try a different order of the options, like so: `-cfm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Manifest is a file named "MANIFEST.MF" in the META-INF directory. So, you need to have your final code look like this on the filesystem:

```
HelloWorld.class
WEB-INF
    MANIFEST.MF
```

Then jar that up in its entirety.

Finally, you should also put your HelloWorld.class in to an actual package:

```
package pkg;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Then your final product will look like:

```
pkg
    HellowWorld.class
META-INF
    MANIFEST.MF
```

And your final class name will be `pkg.HelloWorld`.

Things simply work better with actual packages in Java, it's best to use them right away and avoid trouble.

Note: Oh my mistake, I didn't catch the use of the -m flag -- So used to larger projects where the Manifest is just part of the build artifact.